# How to allow nullable in Flask framework

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've created a table that has following attributes:

```
def complaint():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("complaint.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.form
        data = {
            "name": data.get('name'),
            "number": data.get('number'),
            "address": data.get('address'),
            "content": data.get('content'),
        }
        c = Contact(username=data['name'], number=data['number'], address=data['address'], issues=data['content'])
        db.session.add(c)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("complaint.html", error="Success")
```

But the html shows the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, "Column 'address' cannot be null")
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it should be `nullable` or `blank` (or maybe `blank` was in Django). Maybe use `get('address', "")` to get empty string instead of `None` and then you will have empty string instead of `null`

Comment: how do you created database? Did you create it manually in MySQl or you run python code to create it? Maybe you created it with different options then you have in Flask code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I use ('address', "")and it works now. I use python code to set up database and also change some attributes in MySQL. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `nullable=True` when you define address column in your model.